# peers info are not showing up when node is started

Tags: substrate-node-template

When I start a template-node as below I get only these concise info :

```
~/substrate-node-template$ ./target/release/node-template --chain=local --base-path /tmp/validator1 --alice --node-key=c12b6d18942f5ee8528c8e2baf4e147b5c5c18710926ea492d09cbd9f6c9f82a --port 30333 --ws-port 9944
2022-08-06 13:32:59 〽️ Prometheus exporter started at 127.0.0.1:9615    
2022-08-06 13:32:59 creating instance on iface 192.168.1.6    
2022-08-06 13:32:59 creating instance on iface 172.18.0.1    
2022-08-06 13:32:59 creating instance on iface 172.17.0.1    
2022-08-06 13:33:03 Accepting new connection, 1/100
2022-08-06 13:33:04  Idle (0 peers), best: #1807 (0xcec7…1a55), finalized #1805 (0xb25a…7110), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
```

I am expecting rather to have something similare to
[image]

What am i missing?

Comment: And this https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4105/the-substrate-node-template-of-version-0-9-26-does-not-display-node-identity-inf

Comment: did you solve this problem??